# Analyzing react app performance using chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

For my react application, I am using chrome developer tool to record the performance. But I am not able to point out to specific function that is computationally intensive.

Can someone tell me how to find out the specific function/areas in the code that are taking a lot of time?

[image]

Leads here is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may sort by "Self time" rather then Total time. Even on your screen you may notice that grid.js takes 14.6 ms as "Self time" i.e. 140 times bigger compared to majority of the others on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Look for extension [***react developer tool***](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi)